# Vertical alignment issue on browser width resize

Tags: html, image, resize, jscript

I have a webpage with a image placed onto it. the webpage the image is placed onto is a very long vertical page (4000px) for silly idea reasons.

The image I am placing is of a robot charging out of a city backdrop and I can hover over it and it fades into view. I've been testing out different browsers etc and the Firefox Mobile/Tablet scale view etc and it brought to my attention a few issues.

I've stabilized every other image in the webpage but 1. the robot: for some reason it just will not stay in one place when it resizes. When I Shift the Width scale of a window, the robot shrinks (as wanted) But also scales up or down from its original position.

I've been trying to suss it and no matter what solution, the robot will not stay in the same place and resize. It will always move up or down away from its original position due to resizing. I also cannot have the image at 100% as it's then far too large for the picture.

And because of it being a 4000px vertical screen, no matter how I resize the original image it will always stretch to suit the 4000px.

So I'm a bit stuck. Here is a little code to see if anybody can adjust this so the robot fits.

```
 <style type="text/css">

.container{
    width:100%;
    hieght:100%;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    };
</style>


<style type="text/css">
    .bakimg{

  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}
</style>


  <style type= "text/css">

  #rob{


  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  left:54.5%;
    width:45%; 
  height: 45%;   
  };

  </style>


  <style type= "text/css">

.robofade {

  -webkit-opacity: 0.1;
  -moz-opacity: 0.1;
  opacity: 0.1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
}

.robofade:hover {


  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
}
</style>  




       <script type="text/javascript" src="sound-mouseover.js"></script>

</head>



<body> 

<Div class="container">



   <img class="bakimg" src="webapp1b2.png";>


   <img id="rob" class="robofade" src="robot1a.png";> 


   <embed  src="menulista.html" style="position:fixed; top:0%;left:8.0%; width:100%; height:10%; z-index:100000;">


   <img id="bakbar" src="backbar.png" style="position:fixed; top:0%; left:0%;width:100%; hieght:100%; z-index:9999;">

  <img id="txt" src="linkmywebsitelogotext.png" style="position:fixed; top:1%; left:5%; width:90%; hieght:90%; z-index:9999;">


  <!---<img name="slidetext1" class="fadeout" src="menuslide1.png" style="position:absolute; top:100%; left:26%; width:60%; hieght:100%;">--->


  </div>


  <!--  <img name="glowtxt" class="fadeout" src="glowtext.png" style="position:fixed; left:0.05%; top:90%;  z-index:99999;">-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> 
<body>
```

I am assuming that the issue is due to the large vertical image (4000px) throwing the size differential out of sync...

I can diagonally shift the window size and the image stays put in the correct position, but because of the large vertical backdrop. When i resize the width only of the image - i get the out of position issue... Thanks for any advice in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7239/

like this fiddle , but with a image that has to be at 40% size on a 4000px background image...Tricky . the 40% image just will not stay put... and i cant go 100% or the image is too big....

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it, for those in the same position, it really is an easy fix... see code...

```
<!----responsive elements (images on images---->       
       <style>

       .wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  }

        .bg {
      width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;


        }

        .simg{  

  position:absolute;
  right: 15.3%;
  top: 3.5%;
  height:16%;
  width: 40%;
  max-width:65%;

  opacity: 0.1

  }

  .slidetxt1{  

  position:absolute;
  right: 20%;
  top: 28%;
  width: 60%;
  max-width:60%;
  opacity: 0.1



}

    </style>

</head>


<body> 


<div class="wrapper";>
<img class="bg" src="webapp1b2.png";>
<img id="slide" class="simg" src="robot1.png"; onmouseover="enlarge2()"; onmouseout="delarge2()";> 
<img id="simg" class="slidetxt1" src="menuslide1.png" onmouseover="enlarge()"; onmouseout="delarge()";>
 <div>

 <!--------------------->


   <embed  src="menulista.html" style="position:fixed; top:0%;left:8.0%; width:100%; height:10%; z-index:100000;">


   <img id="bakbar" src="backbar.png" style="position:fixed; top:0%; left:0%;width:100%; hieght:100%; z-index:9999;">

  <img id="txt" class="spinx" src="linkmywebsitelogotext.png" style="position:fixed; top:1%; left:5%; width:90%; hieght:90%; z-index:9999;">



  <!--  <img name="glowtxt" class="fadeout" src="glowtext.png" style="position:fixed; left:0.05%; top:90%;  z-index:99999;">-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> 
<body>
```